# Slow data connection in one form

Tags: infopath, data-connection

We have an issue in one form where when a data connection is pulled in there is an unbearable load time (at least 5 minutes!). This was singled out by stopping the connection on load and having the loading triggering on a rule inside the form. 
The strange thing is that we have other forms running the same connection without much loading.

Any suggestions are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: so, what type of form is this - infopath? What type of connection? Are you connecting to a database, web service, other ?

Comment: This is an infopath 2010 form on sharepoint 2010, connecting to a sharepoint list.

Comment: do you have a lot of controls and rules in the form? If so, you might start by breaking the form out into different views.

Comment: The forms is quite large, however it is not insanely large. Can the problem be control related if the wait happens from running the connection on a rule within the form (when this happens there is no delay on initial load)?

Comment: yes, it can be coming from one of your controls on the form. I'd check your drop downs ... maybe try taking one off at a time to try and find which one.

Comment: I have removed all drop downs that use the connection that is causing the issue and there is no improvement in speed - this is looking more and more like using a webservice to fetch the data could be the only fix for this

Comment: How large is the list? In my experience InfoPath forms can take a crazy long time to load if the list they're sitting on is large.

Comment: Die you try to Figuren out the Transfers data with fiddler? Maybe there will be loaded much more data as allowed?

Answer (score -1):

Here is article to help trouble shoot your issues http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380251(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)